# Why is the default localhost on many application/ frameworks set to :8000 or something similar like :8080?

Tags: localhost, port

The question is what is the origin of using port `:8000`?

[8080 is by far the most popular](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%3A8080)

[8000 is second](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%3A8000)

Comment: Port 80 is the default port for HTTP, so a lot of applications won't use that by default to avoid clashing with existing applications that are using port 80. Port 8080 looks similar to port 80, so you see that used a lot (for example, I believe that's Nginx's default for server blocks), and 8000 also looks similar to 80. The idea, I believe, is to use a number that is easily recognized as the default HTTP port without actually using the default HTTP port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per https://www.grc.com/port_8080.htm

Description:
This port is a popular alternative to port 80 for offering web services. "8080" was chosen since it is "two 80's", and also because it is above the restricted well known service port range (ports 1-1023, see below).

Background:
"The Internet was largely born on UNIX-based systems and servers. UNIX enforces the notion of the first 1023 "privileged ports" which can only be opened by services running with so-called "root", or administrative, privileges. Historically, this meant that only authorized system administrators were able to establish and operate a web server on port 80 since this was within the first 1023-port privileged region. Therefore, when non-administrators wished to run their own web servers on machines which might already have a server running on port 80, or when they were not authorized to run services below port 1024, port 8080 was often chosen as a convenient place to host a secondary or alternate web server."

Long story short... it looks like 80 without being 80 which is within the "restricted port range" of Unix based systems (which are more or less the foundation or at the very least the initial foundation of the Internet and modern computing in general).  Though I cannot find specific documentation about it I'm sure 8000 is for similar reasons.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP runs over port 80. So 8080 is simply two 80's. Also, because it is above the restricted service port range of 1-1023. Using it in a URL requires it to be explicit, and not defaulted

Comment: what are their really restricted ports?

Answer (score 1):

The port `8000` is considered as a alternative http port. This port is commonly uses TCP port 8000 including:

> Winamp Audio Streaming, X-Lite, Icecast, DynamoDB Local, Nicecast/Icecast, Dell OpenManage, Django Dev Server, Nortel Firewall User Authentication, Barracuda Web Administration, PFSense, and VmWare VMotion and many more. Some games like aliens vs predator also uses this port (UDP).

Most of the times os don't care which port you are using unless its busy. Its just a port for os and it does not matter to it.